# Why can the sieve of eratosthenes not be used to confirm the twin primes conjecture?

Tags: prime-numbers, twin-primes, sieve-theory

I have been having fun thinking about sieves and more particularly the twin prime conjecture. As I am fairly new to this type of mathematics, I am wondering, if we use the sieve of erastothenes, aka marking of multiples of primes, and we can see that between each step of the sieve the product of all primes below and the prime we are evaluating itself are the middle between two unmarked numbers. So seeing that the number of unmarked numbers stays infinite, won't that make for infinitely many twin primes?

Comment: Can you elaborate on "the product of all primes below and the prime we are evaluating itself are the middle between two unmarked numbers"?

Comment: The sieve is not used to prove there are infinitely many primes so much as to exhaustively list all primes. So I don't think it will prove it for twin primes either.

Comment: @GregoryGrant Sorry for being unclear, if we have 2 * 3 * 5 * 7 ... * pi where pi is the prime we are sieving the multiples of out, that number and any multiple of that number have that number -1 and that number +1 unmarked, as the closest marked number have to be atleast 2 away because that is the smallest prime. This is because we can percieve the aforementioned product as marked by all numbers and so distances of other marked numbers should be the prime numbers in the product itself.

Comment: @GregoryGrant but if we sieve out multiples of primes, and between the sieving of each prime the number cannot become finite, it has to have infinitely many primes right?

Comment: I don't see how you know after sieving $n$ primes that you haven't at that point crossed out every single number greater than the $n$-th prime.  The ancient proof of the infinitude of primes is due to Euclid and uses a completely different argument.  I don't think it follows just from the sieve.  Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Okay, I'm doing a bad job at saying what I want. I mean in better terms, lets say we have an integer that is the product of all primes, when we take that number - 1 and that number + 1, those have to be primes, because if you take any of the primes out of the product of all primes and then subtract one from the other half, getting the last multiple of that prime (like 2*3*5.. and then take 2*(3*5*.. - 1)) it has to be atleast 2 away from the product of all primes, making the +1 and -1 both prime. Knowing that is a guaranteed twin prime, this also goes for all multiples.  What is bad here?

Comment: @GregoryGrant so my longer better version of the question, what is wrong with this explaination of there being infinite twin primes?

Comment: Ah okay I see what you're doing.  The problem I believe is that if $n$ is the product of all primes then concluding that $n+1$ and $n-1$ are prime requires the assumption that there is a *finite* number of primes, which there isn't.  In general the product of the first $k$ primes, plus one, is not prime, it's only prime if we assume a finite number of primes.

Comment: @GregoryGrant Oh, now I see, thank you for showing me.

Comment: @GregoryGrant That version does not get the essense of what I wanted to ask with the sieving question. Because within sieving for each step we assume those primes, and then we sieve out some more as multiples, but the real deal here is that when you do a sieve it can never have a step that makes the number of twin primes finite. Assuming a sieve will eventually be the prime numbers, there should also be infinite prime numbers as when the sieve has gone to infinity It could not have made the list of twin primes finite. right?

Comment: SOE is a mathematical utensil.  Though the logic you present might be flawed, there is nothing mathematical that says it could not be employed to verify the TPC.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, because although the number of unmarked numbers stay infinite, the sieve of Eratosthenes algorithm is very limited in predicting what numbers will stay unmarked before it gets to those numbers.

Let's say $n$ is a very large even integer, bigger than a googolplex. Clearly $n$ is not prime, because it is a nontrivial multiple of $2$. Maybe both $n - 1$ and $n + 1$ are primes, which would mean a twin prime pair. Or maybe either $n - 1$ or $n + 1$ is divisible by some large prime $p < \sqrt{n}$ (and no smaller primes), while the other number is itself prime. But if that's the case, the algorithm won't know until it gets around to evaluating the multiples of $p$.

The $n$ I'm suggesting is too large for your typical computer to do much with. Therefore, for an exercise, I suggest you try $n = 3 \times 2^{128}$ instead. You should find that neither $n - 1$ nor $n + 1$ is prime, and that one of them has a least prime factor you would not immediately think of, while the other one does.

Answer (score 4):

Note that $2\cdot 3\cdot 5\cdot 7\pm1$ is not a pair of twin primes: $2\cdot 3\cdot 5\cdot 7-1=11\cdot 19$.